# BufferedReader "Unknown Source"

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a file which contains a product description, productCode and a productPrice. I have it so that it will set the variables of Product with each new line until it equals null:

```
public class ReadFile {

static ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

public static void main(String[] args){

    String line;

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/data.txt"));

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setDescription(bufferedReader.readLine());
            product.setProductCode(bufferedReader.readLine());
            product.setUnitPrice(Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine()));
            System.out.println(product);
            products.add(product);
            }
    bufferedReader.close();
    }   
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");

}}
```

However I get a error when It comes to getting the next product in the file (Pear):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Pear"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at controller.ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:24)
```

This is how the file is set out:

```
Apple /r 01 /r 99 /r Pear /r 02 /r 88
```

Note: /r Used to represent new line in file.

Where am I going wrong so that it will create a new Product, set the information and repeats until the line equals null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading twice for the Product type. Just use the value of `line` variable to set the Product Description.

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
  // line has already stored information about the Product type.
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setDescription(line); // set value using line variable
            // product.setDescription(bufferedReader.readLine()); // error
            product.setProductCode(bufferedReader.readLine());
            product.setUnitPrice(Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine()));
            System.out.println(product);
            products.add(product);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of your loop you invoke `readLine()` 4 times, but your file format seems to only have 3 lines per "product".  Clearly, one of your calls to `readLine()` is superfluous. Hint: it is the one whose return value you disregard.